# How to build network sniffer in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I would like to get network traffic of one application. So i need to see request and response data, just same as google chrome do at at network tab of developer tool.
What is the best way to do this? Which package can help me?

I have tried node pcap, but documentation is out of date and i didn't find any information how to get body data of request